# Any idea why images are occasionally breaking?

Tags: windows, image, iis, coldfusion

I just upgraded from a Windows 2003 Server (IIS 6) to a Windows 2012 R2 (IIS 8.5). I don't think it matters, but I also upgraded from ColdFusion 9 to ColdFusion 11. All of a sudden images would show as missing. For example, in the search results, the image with the first result will be broken. When I refresh the page, it is there.

I just can't figure it out and our Marketing VP is getting a little antsy... understandably so.

I view the source and the image path is correct. I even copy and paste it into the browser and the image shows.

Has anyone else experienced this? I appreciate any advice you may offer.

Comment: Images load asynchronously. It's possible when you reload, enough of the page was cached the first time that the 'missing' images show up right away. If the image is using the correct path, I don't know what else the issue could be... does that page use a ton of images?

Comment: I suppose it is a little image heavy (2 - 3 dozen images), but there wasn't a problem until I upgraded the server/IIS.

Comment: Do you have more than one web server that are load balanced? Check your 404 logs for clues.

Comment: @cjblonda on a certain page, is it always the SAME images that fail to load at first?

Comment: Almost sounds like a browser issue. Can you share the url of this problematic page?

Comment: it is not always the same images... it varies which is what I find so frustrating! The search results page: http://www.acis.com/trips#/?freetext=italy&its=1

Comment: I see that it's a 404. But then when I inspect the image I see the thumbnail just fine, it loads the resource. Where are these images coming from? Are they static files or generated on the fly?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at your browser's Dev Tools (this is from Chrome). There should be a Network panel that will show all the images being loaded on your site. If there are any real missing images, you'll see a status of 404 (Not Found), otherwise you should see 200 (OK) or 304 (Not Modified). You'll also see a time column that can tell you if any images are just taking some time to load.

[image]

If you're directly showing the image on the page simply by sourcing the image file itself, then your latency shouldn't have anything to do with ColdFusion.

`<img src="/path/to/some.jpg">`

But if you're loading the images using `cfcontent`, then you need to figure out what's going on in relation to ColdFusion.

`<img src="/path/to/some.cfm?fileID=1234">`

Our upgrade from CF 9 to CF 2016 with an upgrade to Windows server on the 2016 boxes is in our Beta environment at the moment and we haven't seen any issues related to loading files (jpg, gif, doc(x), xls(x)) via `cfcontent`.

Comment: I sure appreciate you assistance, but I still can't figure this out. It sound reasonable that it is a browser issue, but then I don't understand why it doesn't happen on the Windows 2003 with IIS6, but does on the Win 2012 with IIS8.5! The site code and images are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out. On our 32-bit 2003 servers, we had to use the Ionic Rewriting tool. Great tool, truly. I installed that on our new 64-bit 2012 server (yes, I used the new 64 bit version). I really don't know why, but when I installed thet Microsoft IIS rewrite module, wrote the filters and uninstalled the Ionic ISAPI filter... voila! The problem went away. I guess the Ionic rewrite tool doesn't play as well with IIS 8.5 as I'd hoped.